# Autopliot API - Trigger Journey - How to make it work?

Tags: php, twilio

I'm struggling with the Autopilot API (http://docs.autopilot.apiary.io/).

I have a trigger journey to set up: when a post-method form is sent, I want to send a SMS (through Twilio) and an email (through Sendgrid) to the user with the information he filled the form with.

So far I understood that a Trigger Journey would be the best solution: I would place an API call in the code dealing with the form submit, and that trigger would send the SMS + the email via Autopilot.

Here's the thing: I don't know AT ALL where to begin. The docs speak about an HTTP Request to include the API key, then I have no clue of what to do to make the trigger work.

Hop you can help with this! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Learn from this [url](http://docs.autopilot.apiary.io/)

Answer (score 1):

I am also working in Autopilot API integration for adding a contact to a journey.

In [Autopilot API Documentation](http://docs.autopilot.apiary.io/), To view the example code for "**[Adding a contact to a journey](http://docs.autopilot.apiary.io/#reference/api-methods/trigger-journey/add-a-contact-to-a-journey)**", Kindly click on the particular title. Once you click on the title, a page section will be opened in right side of the page.

For example, please see the below image.

[image]

**For the comment:**

From Official Documentation

**Add Contact to a list**

It is possible to add a contact and add them to a list in a single API call, you just need to provide an additional contact field called *_autopilot_list​* with the list id, **e.g."_autopilot_list​": "contactlist_91053049-5582-40B4-A17F-78ADF8F25663"**

You can obtain the list name with the fetch lists command documented in this API, or through the URL bar in your browser when viewing the list in Autopilot.If you provide this along with the request it will both add the contact and add them to the list.

Comment: I'm just curious, has anyone ever gotten the feature to work when you add a contact, you can automatically add them to a list if you provide a field "_autopilot_list​" => "contactlist_xxxxxx_" I am not able to get this to work as the docs specify.